# Iteration across M x N matrix in pseudocode?

Tags: php, math, xslt, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Well, I can't post code because of some bug, so I'm going to pseudocode you guys.  Please, respond with code and math.  I am terrible at math, and trying to figure math out via code is an impossible task for me.

My psuedocode uses only numbers and letters, which will form a 2x2 matrix, but I want to be able to iterate across m by n matrices in this fashion.  I just think that it's easier to go from specific (no variables) to general (variable-inclusive).

```
Letter a, letter b; number 1, number 2 ==>

Letter a id=1, letter b id=1 | 
number 1 id=1, number 2 id=2 |
Letter_by_Number 1by1, Letter_by_Number 1by2, Letter_by_Number 2by1, Letter_by_Number 2by2
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in C++, Python, PHP's SimpleXML, or XSL?  If I can get the math down in any of these languages, I think I can figure everything else out.

Comment: Also, is this correct: `foreach ($m as $valueM) {foreach ($valueM as $n) {echo "$valueM"."x"."$valueN}};`?

Comment: Re: your comment: You are missing a double-quote after `$valueN`, and the semicolon is in the wrong place.

Comment: @OP: suggest you edit the title of this question. We don't know whether it is driving you insane or it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$m = 2; 
$n = 2; 

for($i = 1; $i <= $m; $i++) {
    for($j = 1; $j <= $n; $j++) {
         echo $i." x ".$j."\n"; 
    }
}
```

Results:

```
1 x 1
1 x 2
2 x 1
2 x 2
```

Comment: I like your answer because it's completely self contained, and it gives a result in php, which is a language that anyone can test online at viper.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to iterate through a 2-dimensional array. In pseudocode you'd do something like:

```
for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) {
  for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) {
    do stuff with array element i,j
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll test it to see if it is going to get 1xa, 1xb, 2xa, 2xb in echo.

Comment: I think it's more difficult than that.  There has to be a way to discover M and N, right?

Comment: Maybe: `$i == array(1, 2); $j == array(a, b); $m == count_array($j); $n == count_array($i); for ( $i = 0; $i < m; i++ ) {for ( $j = 0; j < n; j++) { echo $i."x"$j }}`